# Tkinter callback

Tags: python, button, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a Tkinter problem with callback in `button1`. When I click `button1` I want the SearchIP method to get called, but I am getting this error message:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1764, in __getattr__
return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: SearchIP
```

This is my code attempt so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
 try:
# for Python2
import Tkinter as tk
import ScrolledText as tkst
 except ImportError:
# for Python3
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst

global Filename

root=tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root,width=100)
label=Label(root,text="http://")
label.grid(row=0,column=0)
entryVar =tk.StringVar()
entry=Entry(root,width=50,textvariable=entryVar)
entry.grid(row='0',column='1',columnspan=8)
root.button1 = Button(root,text="Search IP",command= root.SearchIP)
root.button1.grid(row=1,column=0)
button2=Button(root,text ="DNS Recon")
button2.grid(row=1,column=1)
button3=Button(root,text ="Port Scanner")
button3.grid(row=1,column=2)
button4=Button(root,text ="Web Crawl")
button4.grid(row=1,column=3)
button5=Button(root,text ="Email Gathering")
button5.grid(row=1,column=4)
frame.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=30,rowspan=30)
edit_space = tkst.ScrolledText(
master = frame,
wrap   = 'word',  # wrap text at full words only
width  = 45,      # characters
height = 10,      # text lines
     # background color of edit area
 )
     # the padx/pady space will form a frame
edit_space.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=8, pady=8)
root.title("E-Z Security Audting")

mytext = '''\
 Man who drive like hell, bound to get there.
 Man who run in front of car, get tired.
 Man who run behind car, get exhausted.
 Man who run in front of car, get tired.
 Man who run behind car, get exhausted.
 Man who drive like hell, bound to get there.
 Man who run in front of car, get tired.
 Man who run behind car, get exhausted.
     '''
 edit_space.insert('insert', mytext)
 def  SearchIP(root):
    mytext="hello"


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: use `command=SearchIP` and `def SearchIP():`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SearchIP()` is not part of `tk` or `root` so use `command=SearchIP`

And use `def SearchIP():` - you don't have to pass `root` as argument.

--

If you need to pass argument to `SearchIP(some-argument)` then you have to use `command=lambda:SearchIP(passed-argument)`

Answer (score 1):

SearchIP() is called before it is defined. The error message is simply saying that the interpreter doesn't know what SearchIP is at the time the call to that function is made higher up in the script. To fix that move the definition of SearchIP up above the call or move the call down below the definition, or both.

Answer (score 1):

Try , to Use `command=SearchIP` and define SearchIP before calling `root.button` but after calling `root=to.Tk()`. And don't pass argument to function SearchIP as you are using commond argument of button, if you need to pass argument use lamda function. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use Command=SearchIP
And you must place this function just before the button or after import..